# $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$ and $[x]$ are the same concept?

Tags: functions

The function $f(x)$ integer part of $x$ is defined as the largest integer less than or equal to $x$. Generally I have always use this symbol to indicate the integer part of $x$

$$f(x)=[x]$$
instead of

$$f(x)=\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor.$$
Are there some differences or are they represent the same quantity?

Comment: Depending on context / author, $[x]$ may mean the nearest integer (i.e. round instead of floor or ceiling). See e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_integer_function).

Comment: This is the same object. Both notations are used.

Comment: @Bungo Thank you very much for your comment (+1). In mathematical analysis I have always used $[x]$. In combinatorial geometry I have used the $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$.

Comment: If this bothers you, then get ready for binomial coefficients... I've seen no less than 8 variations on notation for that.

Comment: @Mark Thank you also to you. I have appreciated all the comments.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Genuinely curious, what are those $8$ variations? I've only ever seen ${}^nC_k$ and $\binom nk$.

Comment: @YiFan $\binom{n}{k},~\binom{k}{n}$ (*yes, some places flip which goes on top vs bottom*), $~_nC_k,~^nC_k~C^n_k,~C^k_n$ (*see previous*) $~\text{Binom}(n,k),~C(n,k),~(n)_{k}$ (*made more confusing as this pochhammer symbol is also sometimes used for falling factorial instead*)

Comment: If $\lfloor x \rfloor$ *doesn't* mean the largest integer less than or equal then what *does* it mean? Things mean what we say they mean.  But... okay, no, mathematicians don't have some subtle different meaning for it.  It (often called the "floor" function) is a function $\lfloor\ \rfloor:\mathbb R \to \mathbb Z$ via $\lfloor x\rfloor= n$  where $n$ is the unique integer so that $n\le n < n+1$.  Personally I find it for more clear to read but a real pain to type.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for your precious comment. Thank you again.

Comment: @fleablood I'm very glad that I'm having severals comment for my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$[x]$ is the older notation for the largest integer that does not exceed $x$. [Earliest Uses of Various Mathematical Symbols](http://jeff560.tripod.com/functions.html) says

> **Greatest integer function (floor function).** Until recently $[x]$ has been the standard symbol for the greatest integer function. According to Grinstein (1970), "The use of the bracket notation, which has led some authors to term this the *bracket function*, stems back to the work of Gauss (1808) in number theory. The function is also referred to by Legendre who used the now obsolete notation $E(x)$." The Gauss reference is to *Theorematis arithmetici demonstratio nova*. [Werke Volume: Bd. 2](http://134.76.163.65/servlet/digbib?template=view.html&id=137226&startpage=7&endpage=12&image-path=http://134.76.176.141/cgi-bin/letgifsfly.cgi&image-subpath=/3588&image-subpath=3588&pagenumber=7&imageset-id=3588) p. 5.
>
> Recently the symbol $\lfloor x \rfloor$ has come into use. It was introduced in 1962 by Kenneth E. Iverson who also coined the name *floor function*. [...]

$\lfloor x \rfloor$ has two advantages: it is completely unambiguous (there is nothing else it is used for) and it has a mnemonic symmetric partner in $ \lceil x \rceil $, the *ceiling function*. Examples of use:
$$ \begin{align}
 \lfloor 2 \rfloor &= 2 & \lceil 2 \rceil &= 2 \\
 \lfloor 2.5 \rfloor &= 2 & \lceil 2.5 \rceil &= 3 \\
 \lfloor -1 \rfloor &= -1 & \lceil -1 \rceil &= -1 \\
 \lfloor -1.5 \rfloor &= -2 & \lceil -1.5 \rceil &= -1 \\
 \lfloor \pi \rfloor &= 3 & \lceil \pi \rceil &= 4
\end{align} $$

Comment: Thank you a lot lot for your excellent explanation. Do you can put any example for $\lfloor x \rfloor$ and $\lceil x \rceil$ so I can show my high school students the two quantities so I have everything in one answer? Thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano Added, will that suffice?

Comment: Approved and thank you everybody.

Comment: I'm very happy that for my question you have received severals upvote. It is correct :-) Always thank you.

Comment: Learn something new …. I thought that $\lfloor\,\cdot\,\rfloor$ was invented by Knuth when he wrote $\TeX$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think most of us probably did. Perhaps not surprising that Iverson invented it... he probably wanted the square brackets for [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Comment: Yeah, I guess "most probably did" was where I heard it from. And I approve of what Iverson used the old Gauß brackets for, it's **very** convenient sometimes.